# Looping through a char pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am writing a function in which I open a file, then read it line by line and then write down the individual characters from the file to another file.

Like if fileInput has content

```
one
```

the fileOut should has content

```
o
n
e
```

This is my code, not really sure why it doesn't work

```
// Assume I have opened the file in the right modes
char *line = NULL; // Initial storage for storing lines
size_t len = 0;    // Store the length (can I omit it?)
ssize_t read;      // For getline
char *letter;      // For storing the individual characters

while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fin)) != -1) {

    // I believe by this I get the mem address of line in letter and 
    // then check it for end character
    for (letter = line; *letter != '\0'; letter++) {
        fprintf(fout, "%s\n", *letter);
        // Now this will put the entire 'one' 
        // when I really want just o then n and then e.
    }
}
```

Comment: you should do %c in the printf not %s

Comment: What actually is happening?  are you getting errors? segmentation fault?  is it writing the wrong characters to your file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `letter` is already a pointer, you have a couple of options. You can either tell `fprintf` that you are outputting a single character:

```
fprintf(fout, "%c\n", *letter);
```

or, using a slightly more method, you can tell it to output a string of only one character:

```
fprintf(fout, "%.1s\n", letter);
```

Either should work in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
fprintf(fout, %s\n", *letter);
```

to:

```
fprintf(fout, %c\n", *letter);
              ^^^
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I actually tried this already. But I was using `printf` for debugging. Like `printf("%c", *letter);` Would still return `one` one, not `o`. While `fprintf(fout, "%c\n", *letter)` seems to be writing just `o` only.

Comment: @JohnDoe. That's because you did not put a `\n` in your debugging `printf`.

Comment: @JohnDoe Your first `printf` is lacking the `\n`, so that would output all the chars directly one after another.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. How does `printf` works? Does it tries to print out the entire pointer contents until it encounters the `\n`. I just the read documentation for `printf` but it still remains unclear to me.

Answer (score 2):

You have to print it as a char (`%c`) not as a complete String (`%s`).

Answer (score 2):

`%c` is what you want for printing out a char in a format string. If you use `%s`, that will try to print out a whole string, which is what you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

You try to print a string with *newline character* ('\n') each time when you call:

```
fprintf(fout, "%s\n", *letter);
```

But your *letter is of *char* type.
So you need to print this:

```
fprintf(fout, "%c\n", *letter);
```

This time it will print each character in the line following with a *newline character* ('\n') what you really need.
Your output will be:

> "o\nn\ne\n"

As you see each character is followed by '\n' that means:

```
o
n
e
```